# csv files downloading as txt when using download attribute of <a> tag in PHP

Tags: php, html, csv

I am trying to download File with csv extension using download attribute but it's downloading file with .txt extension.

Here's my code

```
<a href="log_files/log_files/abc.csv" download><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Download</button></a>
```

Help me if you know the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, just add the filename with .csv extension in the download attribute, like below

```
<a href="log_files/log_files/abc.csv" download="abc.csv"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Download</button></a>
```

Comment: Wait. The `<button>` is unnecessary too. If OP is using Bootstrap as CSS framework, the classes can move to the `<a>` tag for visual styling.

Comment: @Raptor rather "illegal", than just unnecessary ;-) `a` and `button` are both considered interactive elements, and as such _must not_ be nested into each other.

Comment: Totally agree. HTML Validation will point this out too.